# undefined method "has_attached_file" with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-1.8

I'm getting some unexpected behavior from my app while Upgrading to from Rails 2.3.11 to 3.1, particularly in relation to Paperclip.

I've added the gem 'paperclip' to my Gemfile, and I ran `bundle install` and all seems to go well, except that when I start my server, I get this stack trace

```
...: `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x7f30b32c1f88> (NameError)
...
...
from /home/user/railscamp/app/app/models/organization.rb:76
...
from /home/user/railscamp/app/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/user/railscamp/app/config.ru:1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: how do you mean it's installing to the root directory?

Comment: Actually, I figured out the install directory thing.  I made the mistake of running `bundle install paperclip` thinking it might do what it ought to do, but instead, it installed everything into the 'paperclip/' directory inside the app every time I ran bundle install (w/ or w/o the paperclip option).  So I figured that out and fixed it.  However, the app still seems to ignore the fact that paperclip is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to your model

```
attr_accessor :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at
```

Comment: hehe, i actually had a different problem, but seeing your comment made me realize what else i had forgotten. thx